# Issue with overflowed element width in Edge & IE11

Tags: jquery, angularjs, microsoft-edge

I've done some simple component that looks like this:

```
<div class="container"><span class="text>{{someText}}</span></div>
```

The idea is when text length goes beyond container's width, it will be cut using 'overflow: ellipsis' and on mouseover there would be a tooltip that will show the full text. To calculate if tooltip is needed I just get the width from the container and compare it with the width of the text. If the text's width is bigger, the element is overflowed and I should display the tooltip.

This works well, but not in IE and Edge. The reason is that width, outerWidth and offsetWidth for overflowed text somehow been calculated without the part hidden by overflow. Is there some workfaround to fix this?

Edited: here is the example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dVzwBO

Try to do mouseover on the element in Chrome and Edge and compare the width values.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Added a simple example.

Comment: Just checked in Chromium 63.0.3231.0. Displayed width is 127 px, as expected.
Note, this example doesn't show the tooltip, only the text element's width, since this enough to illustrate the issue.